# Deadlock with more than 2 processes, possible?

Tags: deadlock

Regarding the case of a deadlock, I understand how it works for 2 processes and that it requires a minimum of 2 processes for a deadlock to happen.

> Construct an example to show that it is possible for a deadlock to happen when there are 3, 4 ... n numbers of processes.

Any tips in constructing an example?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't really understand your question ... If you can have a deadlock with two processes it is quite forward that it can happen with more processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deadlocks are likely to occur in more than 2 processes as well. If more processes have locked respective resources that are required to release the other resources held by the prior process then it is a deadlock.

Please refer to this example:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/operating-system-process-management-deadlock-introduction/

if we increase number of dependent resources, a circular dependency is occured and deadlock will occur in N processes (more than 2).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Two threads are in deadlock if one process need the lock of the other and the other way, when having `n threads` you still can have all your threads blocked forever if there is a circular dependency.

Thread1 needs lock of thread2 that needs lock of thread3 ... needs lock of threadn that needs lock of thread1.